# How to assign more than one Sign and switch them quickly?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Just started playing the Witcher 2 recently and found that the sword alone is far from being enough in battle.. Signs must be used, usually more than one - so far I've been able to assign only one, although I see two "placeholders" in the bottom.

So, is it possible and if so how to assign two signs that can be switched quickly or even cast with different buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you select "Options" on the Launcher and then "Input settings", you get to a screen where you can change the keybindings. There are already predefined keys for each sign on the number keys 5-9. You can either use those or redefine them to more convenient keys.

While you hold `Ctrl` to select a sign the time is slowed down considerably, usually that is enough to switch signs in mid-combat. The second slot you see in the bottom left is for throwing daggers, bombs and traps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks perfect - will try that and let you know. :)

Comment: Didn't help me beat those goonies but that's the correct answer nontheless. :-)