# How to quickly switch between signs in the Witcher 2?

Tags: controllers, the-witcher-2

I am playing the Witcher 2 using a XBox360 controller and I find the way the switch between signs to be very clunky.

I have to press LR and then navigate to the sign, and ever so often it seems to lag and my selection jumps an entry too far for my intended sign, making the slowdown effect during the sign selection moot.

This is troublesome especially in the Kayran fight where I have to alternate between Quen and Yrden very often.

Is there a way I can quick switch between signs? It seems to be possible as there are two circles indicating sign places in the lower left HUD of which only my current selection shows up.

Is there a quick switch?

Comment: "It seems to be possible as there are two circles indicating sign places in the lower left HUD" - isn't one of those for displaying what item you currently have selected? Like traps and bombs and stuff

Comment: @Pyritie That's why I have written "seems". I rarely use traps and only use bombs to destroy nests, so what you say might be the actual case.

Comment: Related, but keyboard specific: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-assign-more-than-one-sign-and-switch-them-quickly?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can using the gamepad Options window accessable over the Witcher 2 Launcher:

[image: setting for gamepad]

It's not easy to remap though without causing conflicts, and there is not toggle but when you for example don't use bombs and throwable daggers, you could map RB a specific sign you are using often, e.g. Quen, and stick with the other selection.